# I get duplicates from this SQL query and I think it should just add them up

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my code

```
select 
    name, sum(Value) as [Total Donated]
from 
    CHARITY c 
join 
    DONATION d on c.CharityID = d.CharityID
join 
    ITEM_DONATION id on d.DonationID = id.DonationID
group by 
    name, DonationDate
having 
    DonationDate like '%13%'
order by 
    name;
```

and the output

```
name                 Total Donated
-------------------- -------------
Boy Scouts           250.00
Boy Scouts             5.00
Focus Hope             5.00
Focus Hope            10.00
Fresh Start Charity   12.00
Helping Hands          2.99
Helping Hands         12.50
Helping Hands        110.50
St. John Hospital    112.00
```

I thought I had it set where the Boy Scouts should be one item just added together and same with focus hope and etc....   but I am a bit off somewhere can anyone help and let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove `DonationDate` from the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Column 'DONATION.DonationDate' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `DonationDate` from the `GROUP BY` clause and move the condition from `HAVING` into the `WHERE` clause:

```
select 
    name
    , sum(Value) as [Total Donated]
from CHARITY c 
join DONATION d
    on c.CharityID = d.CharityID
join ITEM_DONATION id
    on d.DonationID = id.DonationID
where
    DonationDate like '%13%'
group by name
order by name;
```

Comment: this is correct, i will mark it in a moment, i got it before i seen it posted here, thanks much for the help